# Windows phone 8.1 universal app create .appx file but not work in nokia lumia 720 device

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I am developing windows phone application. I am having problem on deploying my project.

Error -Deployment failed because no windows phone was detected. Make sure a phone is connected and powered on. But my phone already detected and power also ON .  i have register my windows phone for developer register account.

See: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ftx35jzp0p8s7xi/Error.png?dl=0

Thank you .. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some the issue was resolved by following the below:
Disconnected the Phone from the USB. Then went to 'Control Panel->Hardware and Sound->Devices' and Removed Device. Then connected the Phone to the USB.

Comment: Thanks for you replication. But the issue is still not resolved.

Comment: I'm trying to test a win 8.1 app on nokia lumia 720. But there is some issue in driver installation. Every time it goes like Status: Driver is unavailable. Driver error. Please let me know the best possible solution.